# How do I roll a image like this in js/css

Tags: javascript, image

I wanna zoom in & roll(left to right one by one) an image like this:

(The image is to large to upload)

https://i.imgur.com/sQG1chQ.png

It is for a coinflip system & I want it to go vertically instead of horizontal:)

& you will need to zoom in to see the coins.

Comment: Go from the left to the right(updated post)

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS:

You could do this with keyframes rule using CSS. Animations will take multiple parameters by dividing them with a comma, so you could make an animation for the flip and another for the move.

For the flip a transform: rotateX will do the trick, for the move a position of relative with a ***top*** position starting before top pages fold something like negative height of the image `-2rem` in my case, and moving to a calculated `vh` ***view-height*** off the bottom fold `calc(100vw + 2rem)`.

### EDIT:

I have added a new image and adjusted the `position` of both images to `absolute`, adjusting their ***left*** positions to be the same and then did some tweaking to the @keyframes tween for both image elements. Basically we ***toggle*** `opacity` @ *90 degree flip points* of each image within the tween, also adjust the ***rotation*** to show both images right side up on their respective flips. This is done by starting out on the second image tween `0%` to `rotate(180deg)`, then we *increment* through each ***25%*** by ***90deg***.

```css
#cont {
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#img {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: front 1200ms linear infinite,
    move 5000ms linear infinite;
  position: absolute; /* changed from relative to absolute */  
  left: calc(50vw - 1rem); /* center 50vw minus half the width of image */ 
}

/* Added a second image and adjusted rotate degrees in animation 
   keyframes tween to be exactly 180 degrees offset from 0 
   so second image looks like it is face up on turn, 
   Also added a opacity toggle when between the two images at 90deg and 277deg 
   when they are horizontally aligned on the z axis with top and bottom */
#img2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: back 1200ms linear infinite,
    move 5000ms linear infinite;
  position: absolute; /* changed from relative to absolute */  
  left: calc(50vw - 1rem); /* center 50vw minus half the width of image */ 
}

@keyframes front {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);    
    opacity: 1; /* added opacity starting at 1 0% on first image */
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* switch opacity to 0 here as neither image will be seen as it is 90deg */
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0; /* opacity 0 here */
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg); /* continue rotation */
  }
  74% {
    opacity: 0;  /* opacity 0 here */
  }
  /* switch opacity back on here */
  75% {    
    transform: rotateX(270deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% { 
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes back {
  0% {
    /* start @ 180deg so image is show face up on flip at this  
       point it will be upside down on the x axis */
    transform: rotateX(180deg); 
    opacity: 0; /* start with opacity 0 */
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  /* switch this image to opacity 1 and continue  rotation */
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(277deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  74% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* turn this images opacity to 0 here */
  /* keep flipping image on same rotation, do not go back to 0
     just increment by 90deg with each tween as 360 % 4 = 9 and 100 divided by four = 25
     so every 25% of tween we hit a 90deg rotation*/
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(450deg); 
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% { 
    transform: rotateX(540deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    top: -2rem;
  }
  to {  
    top: calc(100vh + 2rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <img id="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/02/13/51/bitcoin-3125488_640.png">
  <img id="img2" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/27/21/37/bitcoin-2546854_960_720.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have the image cuz then can I add a 3d coin with sides, I've been trying with CSS img & ::after but ::after wont work on chrome..

Comment: @relz you can simply add a new image and adjust position of both images to ***absolute***, adjust their ***left*** position to be the same and then do some tweaking to the `@keyframes` tween for both image elements. Basically you will toggle ***opacity*** @ *90 degree* flip points of each image within the tween, also adjust the ***rotation*** if you wish to show both images right side up on their respective flips. I have added notes in the CSS outlining the changes I made.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing :) Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try rotating the image and animating the `margin-left`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('img').style.marginLeft = "-10000px";
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

img {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: 60s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sQG1chQ.png" height="50">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Only thing is that I need it to stop on the last coin & stay there